# ReactJs - creating a dynamic list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a card game. I have this json db:

```
{
  "characters": [   
    {    
      "name": "Character1",
      "punch":12,
      "kick":12,
      "special":15,
      "image":"character1"

    },
    {    
      "name": "Character2",
      "punch":13,
      "kick":11,
      "special":15,
      "image":"character2"  
    },         

    {   
      "name": "Character3",
      "punch":20,
      "kick":19,
      "special":10,
      "image":"character3"   
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this parent component that fetches the json data to pass for a child component. The data is fetched successfully.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Player from './Player'

var data = require('./db.json');

class Stage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      characters: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      characters: data.characters
    })  
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="stage">
      {console.log(this.state.characters)}
        <Player data={this.state.characters}/>
        <Player data={this.state.characters}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Stage
```

Now I want to render each card for each character inside this component in a dynamic `<li>`. For example, I have 3 characters so I want to render 3 cards. Each one that matches for a character. How can I do it? I want to pass the properties for the `<Card>` component to

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from './Card'   

const Player = (props) => { 
  return (
    <div className="player">     
      <Card/>  
    </div>
  )
}


export default Player
```

Comment: ok, so what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to render a dynamic html list each one with a character into the card

Comment: see the second component

Comment: as a good practice and SO etiquette, try to mention what you have tried before posting, draft your question under requirement and problem statement headings. Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you want to use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Basically you take an array, and return a set of react components from that array. For example:

```
const Player = ({ data }) => { 
  return (
    <div className="player">
      {data.map((character, i) => (     
        <Card key={i} name{character.name}/>  
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here I have passed the `name` key down into each card, but you can pass whatever you want (including the entire `character` object if that makes sense).

Also, I would rename `data` to `characters` as this makes more sense. And I would set a default to the prop to be an empty array.

Comment: But I want to do it in the cards, not in the players

Comment: You might need to clarify what you are trying to achieve then. Your json data is an array of what looks like characters. What do the cards represent? Could you provide say your ideal component tree output or something? Either way, what i've put as my answer should be what you need conceptually.

Comment: each card represent each character

Comment: ok updated. As you can see, the answer is still conceptually the same.

Comment: please don't forget ```key=[i]```  for card child.

Comment: @hamedhossani Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use .map() function to loop every item of an array.

> .map()

```
  {data.map((item, i) => (     
    <Card key={i} name={item.name}/>  
  ))}
```